# Writing to an existing Excel Workbook using xlwings

Tags: python, excel, pandas, overwrite, xlwings

I am new to Python and working on a project that I could use some help on.  So I am trying to modify an existing excel workbook in order to compare stock data.  Luckily, there was a program online that retrieved all the data I need and I have successful been able to pull the data and write the data into a new excel file.  However, the goal is to pull the data and put it into an existing excel file.  Furthermore, I need to overwrite the cell values in the existing file.  I believe xlwings is able to do this and I think my code is on the write track, but I ran into an unexpected error.  The error I get is:

```
com_error: (-2147023174, 'The RPC server is unavailable.', None, None)
```

I was wondering if anyone knew why this error came up?  Also, does anyone know how to fix it?  Is it fixable?  Is my code wrong? Any help or guidance is appreciated.  Thank you.

```
import good_morning as gm
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

#import income statement, balance sheet, and cash flow of AAPL
fd = gm.FinancialsDownloader()
fd_frames = fd.download('AAPL')

#Creates a DataFrame for only the balance sheet
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(fd_frames.values())[0])

#connects to workbook I want to modify
wb = xw.Book(r'C:/Users/vince/OneDrive/Documents/Python/Project/spreadsheet.xlsm')

#sheet I would like to modify
sht = wb.sheets[1]

#modifies & overwrites values in my spreadsheet
sht.range('M6').value = df1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing and modifying an existing workbook using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489950/writing-and-modifying-an-existing-workbook-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is discussed in https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/633. It is apparently related to an Excel glitch. A workaround is provided on that github page. Also, the xlwings documentation mentions that you might get an error (not clear if it's this one) if the workbook is already open in Excel.