# Opening, writing, and modifying to an existing workbook using Python

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am new to Python and working on a project that I could use some help on. So I am trying to modify an existing excel workbook in order to compare stock data. Luckily, there was a program online that retrieved all the data I need and I have successful been able to pull the data and write the data into a new excel file. However, the goal is to pull the data and put it into an existing excel file. Furthermore, I need to overwrite the cell values in the existing file. I believe xlwings is able to do this and I think my code is on the right track, but I ran into an unexpected error. The error I get is:

```
com_error: (-2147352570, 'Unknown name.', None, None)
```

I was wondering if anyone knew why this error came up? Also, does anyone know how to fix it? Is it fixable? Is my code wrong? Any help or guidance is appreciated. Thank you.

```
import good_morning as gm
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

#import income statement, balance sheet, and cash flow of AAPL
fd = gm.FinancialsDownloader()
fd_frames = fd.download('AAPL')

#Creates a DataFrame for only the balance sheet
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(fd_frames.values())[0])

#connects to workbook I want to modify (this is where I get the commerror)
wb = xw.Book(r'C:/Users/vince/Project/Spreadsheet.xlsm')

#sheet I would like to modify
sht = wb.sheets[1]

#modifies & overwrites values in my spreadsheet
sht.range('M6').value = df1
```

Comment: Try backslashes in your workbook path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing and modifying an existing workbook using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489950/writing-and-modifying-an-existing-workbook-using-python)