# Overwriting data to an existing workbook using Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlwings

I am new to Python and working on a project that I could use some help on. So I am trying to modify an existing excel workbook in order to compare stock data. Luckily, there was a program online that retrieved all the data I need and I have successful been able to pull the data and write the data into a new excel file. However, the goal is to pull the data and put it into an existing excel file. Furthermore, I need to overwrite the cell values in the existing file. I believe xlwings is able to do this and I think my code is on the right track, but I ran into an unexpected error. The error I get is:

```
TypeError: Objects of type 'Period' can not be converted to a COM VARIANT (but obtaining the buffer() of this object could)
```

I was wondering if anyone knew why this error came up? Also, does anyone know how to fix it? Is it fixable? Is my code wrong? Any help or guidance is appreciated. Thank you.

```
import good_morning as gm
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

#import income statement, balance sheet, and cash flow of AAPL
fd = gm.FinancialsDownloader()
fd_frames = fd.download('AAPL')

#Creates a DataFrame for only the balance sheet
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(fd_frames.values())[0])

#connects to workbook I want to modify 
wb = xw.Book(r'C:\Users\vince\Project\Spreadsheet.xlsm')

#sheet I would like to modify
sht = wb.sheets[1]

#modifies & overwrites values in my spreadsheet(this is where I get the type_error)
sht.range('M6').value = df1
```

**Data Types**:

```
type(fd_frames)
>>> <class 'dict'>
fd_frames.values())[0].info()
>>> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> 
RangeIndex: 22 entries, 0 to 21 
Data columns (total 8 columns): 
parent_index 22 non-null int64 
title 22 non-null object 
2012 19 non-null float64 
2013 20 non-null float64 
2014 20 non-null float64 
2015 20 non-null float64 
2016 20 non-null float64 
2017 20 non-null float64 
dtypes: float64(6), int64(1), object(1) 
memory usage: 1.5+ KB
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing and modifying an existing workbook using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489950/writing-and-modifying-an-existing-workbook-using-python)

Comment: how does pandas.DataFrame.append help?  I have the data frame I want.  I am having trouble overwriting existing data from my excel file with the data frame I have.  I am still confused how I get the data to an existing workbook

Comment: I don't think I am able to update an existing workbook with those functions.  I have searched online and don't think it is possible to do it with these functions.  It is hard to find a function that will modify an existing workplace and replace the data in it. Thank you for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Comments**: You have a **Dict** of `pandas.DataFrame`.

Selecting from a Dict using `list(fd_frames.values())[0]` does lead to **unpredictable** Results. Show the Keys of the Dict and choose the one you interested off using these Key, e.g.:

```
 print(fd_frames.keys())
 >>> dict_keys(['key_1', 'key_2', 'key_n']
 df_2 = fd_frames['key_2']
```

Beside this, neither of the Dimension in your `pandas.DataFrame` does match `M6:M30` = 25. There are only **8 columns** with **20 Values**. Therfore you have to align your Worksheet Range to **20 Rows**. To write Column 2017 to the Worksheet, e.g.:

```
wb['M6:M25'] = df_2['2017'].values
```

> **Note**: I have updated the code below to accept `numpy.ndarray` also.

---

> **Question**: ... the goal is to pull the data and put it into an existing excel file

Update a Workbooks Worksheet Range with List Values.
**Using: OpenPyXL**: [A Python library to read/write Excel 2010 xlsx/xlsm files](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/)

> **Note**: Observe how the List Values have to be arranged!
>   **param values: List: *[row 1(col1, ... ,coln), ..., row n(col1, ... ,coln)]`**

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

class UpdateWorkbook(object):
    def __init__(self, fname, worksheet=0):
        self.fname = fname
        self.wb = load_workbook(fname)
        self.ws = self.wb.worksheets[worksheet]

    def save(self):
        self.wb.save(self.fname)

    def __setitem__(self, _range, values):
        """
         Assign Values to a Worksheet Range
        :param _range:  String e.g ['M6:M30']
        :param values: List: [row 1(col1, ... ,coln), ..., row n(col1, ... ,coln)]
        :return: None
        """

        def _gen_value():
            for value in values:
                yield value

            if not isinstance(values, (list, numpy.ndarray)):
                raise ValueError('Values Type Error: Values have to be "list": values={}'.
                                  format(type(values)))
            if isinstance(values, numpy.ndarray) and values.ndim > 1:
                raise ValueError('Values Type Error: Values of Type numpy.ndarray must have ndim=1; values.ndim={}'.
                                  format(values.ndim))

        from openpyxl.utils import range_boundaries
        min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(_range)
        cols = ((max_col - min_col)+1)
        rows = ((max_row - min_row)+1)
        if cols * rows != len(values):
            raise ValueError('Number of List Values:{} does not match Range({}):{}'.
                             format(len(values), _range, cols * rows))

        value = _gen_value()
        for row_cells in self.ws.iter_rows(min_col=min_col, min_row=min_row,
                                           max_col=max_col, max_row=max_row):
            for cell in row_cells:
                cell.value = value.__next__()
```

> **Usage**
>
> ```
> wb = UpdateWorkbook(r'C:\Users\vince\Project\Spreadsheet.xlsx', worksheet=1)
> df_2 = fd_frames['key_2']
> wb['M6:M25'] = df_2['2017'].values
> wb.save()
> ```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - openpyxl:2.4.1 - LibreOffice:4.3.3.2***

Comment: When I use this code, it is able to put data into an existing workbook file.  However, it overwrites the entire workbook.  I am sorry I was not very clear, but I only want to overwrite certain cells in the existing workbook, not remove all the data from the workbook.  Do you know if this is possible?  Replacing specific cells with the panda data frame I want?  For example I would want to replace cells M6 to M30 in a sheet called data with the data frame created.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want to do without erasing or removing any of the existing data in that spreadsheet.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for the great code!  I still ran into an unexpected error which I don't understand.  For some reason it is giving me a Value Error.  The error states:


ValueError: Values Type Error: Values have to be "list": values=<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>.

This makes no sense to me since we convert the dataframe to a list, but I could be looking at it wrong.  Thank you for all your help.  If you could give me some more advice I would really appreciate it! Thanks again

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format my text in the comments

Comment: Thank you for your help you have been amazing!!! I have few more questions, does this code allow me to choose what sheet in the workbook, I want to put the data in?  Also, do you know how I can convert my data from exponentials (for example, 10e9 to 10 billion) to a unit of billions or millions?  Is there an easy way to get rid of the exponentials?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it all the work you did

Comment: @vdub32: What do you think what the Parameter `worksheet=1` is for? Do a Search on SO `[python] float format`, there are plenty of Answers about this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do a similar procedure for other Stack explorers:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

... create your pandas dataframe df...

# Writing from pandas back to an existing EXCEL workbook
# Load workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename=target, read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
ws = wb['Sheet1']

# Overwrite Existing data in sheet with a dataframe.
rows = dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True)

for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
         ws.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=value)

# Save file
wb.save('outfile.xlsm')
```